# Java Applet (in browser) not working with Java 1.7

Tags: java, browser, applet, java-7

I have a few problems while getting started my Soundrecorder-applet in a browser (Firefox, Safari, Chrome...) I was able to isolate the problem as far discribed below:

**Problem:**

Installed java version: ***6u32***

Compiled java version (applet): 6u32 OR 7u4

**Result:** The applet works without any Problems on following OS's: Windows, Linux, OS x under Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

---

Installed java version: ***7u4***

Compiled java version (applet): 6u32 OR 7u4

**Result:** The applet does **NOT** work on following OS's: Windows, Linux, OS x under Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

---

First conclusion: Applet does not work with the installed version **7u4** of Java!

I also have to mention that I did some required modifications to get my code compiled under java 7.

**build.xml - file:**

```
<target name="build" depends="base">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${bin}" target="1.7">
    </javac>
</target>
```

**org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs:**

- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.7
- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.7
- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.7

Hint: The ***org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs*** should not need to be considered cause the compilation has been made with **Apache Ant Java library**.

Comment: Maybe it´s some kind of policy/security issue, which doesn´t allow to run your applet under 1.7?

Comment: How does it not work?  Have you looked for error messages in the browser's Java console?

Comment: I strongly suspect it is a bug in 1.7.  I tried a sound app. (then simple test codes only a few lines long) in an early version of 1.7 & it crapped out with no sound & no output.  I decided to stick with 1.6 a while more.  Have you checked the bug DB?  We are going to need the console output, as mentioned by Stephen C.  Can you reproduce the effect from the command line, or (failing that) a `JFrame` (easier for others to test)?

Comment: I have tried to get some errors in a java console but I was not successful! I tried to install "Java Console 5.0.12" as firefox add-on but i coudn't download it...I tried all other Consoles which are available as add-on, but none of them arre supporting Java! I tried to start the applet in Eclipse, which should have started the applet in firefox: didn't work. I tried to start the applet in a console; again no chance. Last I tried was to start firefox in a console, to, maybe catch some errors firefox would throw: again no Luck! I was not able to find a way to catch the errors from my applet.

Comment: How are you deploying applets? Are you using Java Deployment Toolkit are <applet>/<object>/<embed> tag?